# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-mate

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , but recently experienced Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and think the Mate version is more what I need.
My question can I download and install it, or can I just upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Mate 16.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download ubuntu mate to install it (you cannot upgrade from normal 16.04 to MATE 16.04)

Download from https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/